# Using composer/Unirest php with Github problems

Tags: php, github, composer-php, unirest

My code works great on my local machine, but when I push my code to github, then download and unzip the folder and move it to my htdocs folder, it says class Unirest is not defined.

I even tried rerunning php composer.phar update/install and it still is saying Unirest is not defined. The code works fine when I push to a Paas, but when I take the .zip from github it won't run.

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: At least it should not be problem with PaaS, When PaaS get your code from github, it's source code then zip and deploy.

Comment: Which PaaS are you using?

Comment: I'm using AppFog, which works great. Only when individuals pull my code from Github it fails. I think the problem was that the vendor folder created by composer should be in my gitignore, then anyone who downloads it has to run php composer.phar install